# Synchronization between 2 systems

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel to migrate data between 2 different systems.

My sync will be executed as a cron each daily.

Basically, I have 5000 rows, I need to copy from 1 DB to another ( I need to process it with Laravel ).

What is the best way to manage such a long script, Nginx will probably gives me a timeout if I do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Increase PHP script execution time

Changes in php.ini
Change max execution time limit for php scripts from 30 seconds (default) to 300 seconds.

```
vim /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

Set

```
max_execution_time = 300
```